# Function to define an area in a colormap and return average pixel value

Tags: matplotlib, colormap, imshow

I have a `.txt` of delimited data, about 600 x 600 cells in size. I have graphed it using matplotlib's `imshow` and now I want to analyze a specific part of interest in it. Particularly, I'm interested in drawing a defined region around a specific (x, y) point and returning the average value (from the file) within that region. I've done some searching but I can't find anything that will let me manipulate this as such. The closest thing I've come to is `patches` or the `patches.Circle` function, but all that does is let me draw a circle around the defined point. I can't extract (or can't figure out how to) any information from there. Here is my working example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

#Setup Plots
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 20})
#Open Data
filename = "smalltest.txt"
data = np.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter = ";", skip_header = 0)

#Colourmap
ax.imshow(data, cmap ='hot', interpolation='nearest')

#-------------------------------------
#Average values around point

#Create circle
circ = patches.Circle((345, 195), 60, alpha=0.8, fc='none', 
edgecolor = 'yellow')
ax.add_patch(circ)

fig.colorbar(ax.imshow(data, cmap ='hot', interpolation='nearest'), 
label = "Temperature (K)")
plt.show()
```

Here is a picture as an example:
[Graph produced. Trying to get average value within the circle that is drawn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoNM1.jpg)

Comment: To draw a static circle, `patches.Circle` is fine; to let the user draw a circle interactively, you can use  an [`EllipseSelector`](https://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.EllipseSelector). To get the data from an array the lies within  a range of coordinates you can create a `numpy.meshgrid` of the coordinates and filter the data by a condition on the coordinates. e.g. `filtered_data = data[(x-x0)**2 + (y-y0)**2 y <= r**2]`. To calculate a mean of an array, `use array.mean()`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Looks like `numpy.meshgrid` is what I was looking for. Thank you very much!